# Prestashop - Member function executeS() on a non-object

Tags: php, nginx, pdo, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have one prestashop web sites.I'm using one modules for xml export it's was perfect before but i move new server and install nginx + php-fqm but not few i try to make new xml export thing giving error

Fatal error: Call to a member function executeS() on a non-object in /modules/prestacenterxmlexportpro/classes/PcXmlProService.php on line 75

That 75. line is inside of getList function that is getlist function

```
public static function getList()
{
    $query = new DbQuery;
    $sql = $query
        ->select('`'.self::$definition['primary'].'` id')
        ->select('`name`')
        ->from(self::$definition['table'])
        ->orderBy('id')
        ->build();
     return self::$db->executeS($sql);
}
```

75. line is **return self::$db->executeS($sql);**

Nginx error log is 
016/03/13 11:15:53 [error] 1034#0: *107886 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function executeS() on a non-object in /modules/prestacenterxmlexportpro/classes/PcXmlProService.php on line 75" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.mywebpage.com, request: "GET /adminroutee12321/index.php?controller=PcXmlPro&addpc_xmlpro_feed&token=b7e61f451c9a702701c2cd0c10174a3a HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "www.mywebpage.com"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `self::$db`, it's a old and poor practice that has been depracted and probably isn't even avaiable in the newer versions of PrestaShop.

Instead, you should be using `Db::getInstance()->executeS`.

Also, `self::$db` is only available in the `ObjectModel` classes or classes that extend it. I can't tell fromm your error whether the class extends `ObjectModel`.

Another reason why `self::$db` might not be working is because you're using `public static function`, meaning that method get's called statically, meaning that `__construct` function isn't called, which would initialize `self::$db = Db::getInstance()`

Comment: Thank you for answer, extends class is ObjectModel. When i use like this 
return self::$db = Db::getInstance($sql); not working any more error but not getting list :/

Comment: But you are genius :) i fixed problem thank you so much i change it like this self::$db = Db::getInstance();
  return self::$db->executeS($sql);